# Calculate/check fill/space coordinates of CSS3 circle / ellipse by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, coordinates, ellipse

I have a circle or, in general, an ellipse defined in CSS e.g. like this:

**circle:** `border-radius: 50%; width: 50px; height: 50px;`

**ellipse:** `border-radius: 50%; width: 30px; height: 50px;`

Now if they would have been square/rectangle I would just use their width and height to calculate/check coordinates. However they are not.

So what I want to do is to calculate drawn ellipse's fill coordinates.

I don't even want to get all of coordinates, because in the end, I actually only need to **check whether or not *some* coordinate is also a coordinate of a given ellipse or not.**

How would I do that using JavaScript(/jQuery)?

**Additional info:**

circle is just a special case(same width&height) of ellipse;

border-radius will always be 50%; 

it does not have to be completely precise;

Comment: Are you tried something or that's a "made my homework" question?

Comment: So you are just trying to confirm that a coordinate is inside a given area?

Comment: You have to show what you have tried. SO is not for "give me teh codez" questions. By showing what you have tried, we can focus on what you're having a hard time with. If we solve the whole problem, then there is no correct answer, there are various ways to achieve what you would like.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I made this on my self :), however I am no math geek, so I hardly now how to calculate area fill / perimeter of a circle :)

Comment: @SethMcClaine sort of - but only where the elipse/circle is drawn - not the whole place it takes (which is square/rectangle)

Comment: @JuanMendes well then provide ways it could be done please :) I am not asking for "give me the code" but if there is something already made / already in API that I don't know of which would do the math...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here.

The first one, and probably one that has passed unawared by you, or maybe you just doesn't care about is that using CSS for shape drawing, although seems to be something quite popular, is not a good approach.

There are a lot of hindrances in this approach, and the most notable one is that CSS isn't a technology developed for vectorial drawing, it's a technology to separate content from style.

You have able technologies at your disposal, like SVG or HTML5 Canvas that will ease your work a lot.

But we'll delve further into this during the second part of the answer:

How do you check that (A,B) is inside a circle of center (x, y) and radius r?

Well, first of all, if your (A,B) point is outside of the rectangle encasing the circle, it will be outside the circle, so if A < x - r || A > x + r || B < y - r || B > y + r your point (A, B) is **outside** of the encasing rectangle.

When (A,B) is inside of the rectangle, the line drawn from (A,B) to (x,y) is the hypothenuse of a rectangle triangle where both other sides are the difference between (A, B) coordinates and the center of your circle, keeping in mind that both points share the same coordinates space.

If you calculate this hypothenuse with Pythagoras Theorem: h = sqrt((A - x)^2 + (B - y)^2).

The points (A,B) where h is greater than r, are **outside** of the circle, while the ones where h is lesser or equal than r, are **inside** of the circle.

[image]

Now, resuming the point of the technology. When you are playing with CSS, it's difficult to count with tools to represent a canvas where you can calculate a true coordinates axis. Sure, you can consider your page as your canvas, but it can be usually affected by external issues, like screen resolution which can destroy your calculations.

My first and **strong** recommendation is to switch to an appropiate technology, like SVG or HTML5 Canvas. Then make sure that you understand the basic geometry concepts I've apported here to the case or a circle (the easy one), and then search on internet or ask here for the case of the ellipse.

Comment: The elements have some settings - can't use canvas, as for SVG, I don't really like using svg as elements, but it could be "last" solution...

Comment: A good answer. This is an example of what we need to learn to take best answers here. :)

Comment: @jae.web you can definitively associate settings to your objects using canvas, just create your objects into your OOP structure with their attribute information and their geometry information, then use those objects information to draw into the canvas. The truly challenge is to reference those objects through click events on canvas, however, there's also a solution for that http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful

Comment: @Bardo nice solution, however I have already everything else completed (the items store settings, are movable,...), so now I am not going to alter it to canvas - however very interesting link, thank you :) , so I guess there is no method in js that already does this, I really need to calculate,...

Comment: @Bardo additionaly - how would be this calculation for elipse, if I may ask ?

Comment: There isn't a method to calculate what you seek for directly. You'll need to struggle with your selected environment to get point and center coordinates, apply the formulae and pray that everyting keeps relative position when rendered on browser

Comment: Complex math is better explained here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76457/check-if-a-point-is-within-an-ellipse

Comment: @Bardo that could solve my problem, honestly I was wondering if there is something like "math stack" and whether to rather post there :) thank you very much :) Do you think you could provide an example image with A,B, x,y , r (english is not my native, so I just want to be sure I get it right) ? :)

Comment: @jave.web image added, I hope it helps clarify the concept